# Eigenvalues of directed Laplacian matrix $L$ and $DL$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, eigenvalues, matrices

I have a weighted Laplacian matrix $L$ of a strongly connected directed graph and a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive entries. Since the graph is directed, $L$ is non-symmetric real. Further, since the graph is strongly connected, $L$ has a simple zero eigenvalue and all its nonzero eigenvalues have positive real part. Is it possible to establish a relation e.g., a bound, between the eigenvalues of $L$ and those of the product $DL$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: hardly, it seems. Think of the Laplacian of the oriented 2-cycle, i.e., $L:=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and take any diagonal matrix $D:=\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & b\end{pmatrix}$. Then $L$ will always have eigenvalues $0,2$, but the eigenvalues of $D\cdot A$ are $0,a+b$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant −1 on the off-diagonal entries of L, but my computations still hold. So, do you possibly want to make more precise what kind of estimates are you hoping for?

Comment: Hi Delio,
thanks for the reply. Let $\sigma(L)$ respectively $\sigma(DL)$ denote the spectrum of $L$ respectively $DL$. Let $D_{ii}$ denote the positive diagonal entries of $D$. I am hoping for an estimate of the form $\sigma(DL)\leq max_i(D_{ii})\sigma(L)$.

Comment: I see. So my example would indeed fit your scheme.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: If you were considering the adjacency matrix (and hence you could apply Perron-Frobenius' theorem, I would see how to work this out using Gelfand's theorem. But in this way...
On the other hand, I do not see how to use strong connectedness. There is a result of Chung (btw: are you using the normalized Laplacian or the usual one?) that yields an upper bound on the diameter using some spectral information - but conversely?

Answer (score 1):

For undirected graphs, Theorem 2.2 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(99)00264-5) might help a bit.

UPDT: Let $G$ be a weighted undirected graph with Laplacian matrix $L$. Let $D$ be a positive diagonal matrix. Let $d=\min(\operatorname{diag}(D))$ and let $\Delta$ be the maximum diagonal entry of $L$. Let $i$ be the weighted [isoperimetric number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheeger_constant_%28graph_theory%29) of $G$. Then:
$$
\lambda_{2}(DL) \geq d \left(\Delta-\sqrt{\Delta^{2}-i^{2}}\right)
$$

Comment: Hi Felix, could you summarize the result for those who do not have access to scidirect? Thanx!

Comment: Isn't that paper on graphs - as opposed to digraphs?

Comment: @DelioMugnolo: Indeed, and I indicated so in my answer. However, perhaps the OP could still derive some insights from it.

Comment: @Suvrit: I added the statement of the theorem. But actually - sciderect have recently put all the old paper of many journals, including LAA, online for free - just try it :) 